# Check if a string to interpolate provides expected placeholders

Tags: python, string-formatting, string-interpolation

Consider this fictitious Python function:

```
def f(s):
    # accepts a string containing placeholders
    # returns an interpolated string
    return s % {'foo': 'OK', 'bar': 'OK'}
```

How can I check that the string *s* provides all the expected placeholders, and if not, make the function politely show the missing keys?

My solution follows. My question: is there a better solution?

```
import sys

def f(s):
    d = {}
    notfound = []
    expected = ['foo', 'bar']

    while True:
        try:
            s % d
            break
        except KeyError as e:
            key = e.args[0] # missing key
            notfound.append(key)
            d.update({key: None})

    missing = set(expected).difference(set(notfound))

    if missing:
        sys.exit("missing keys: %s" % ", ".join(list(missing)))

    return s % {'foo': 'OK', 'bar': 'OK'}
```

Comment: You should use str.format for new code.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I'll surely do. Though reading string module docs I realized that in my example I just need to simple substitute values, not convert or format them in complex ways, so the old (but not deprecated) string.Template would have been even a better choice.

Comment: A general point: don't use `sys.exit` like that. Raise an error instead: it will quit the program like sys.exit, unless the program that called the function has code to handle it. Something like `raise ValueError("missing keys: %s" % ", ".join(list(missing)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a way to see all of the named placeholders using the _formatter_parser method:

```
>>>> y="A %{foo} is a %{bar}"

>>>> for a,b,c,d in y._formatter_parser(): print b

foo

bar
```

For a "public" way:

```
>>>> import string
>>>> x = string.Formatter()
>>>> elements = x.parse(y)
>>>> for a,b,c,d in elements: print b
```

Comment: I'd be more happy to use a non private and documented method, but it doesn't seem to exist. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: There is a public way, but it involves more effort -- edited response