# Python: get string parameters

Tags: python, string, list

I'd like to transform a string expecting a dict of parameters to the list of keys of the expected dict, e.g. find f such that:

```
f("some text %(foo)s %(bar)s") == ['foo', 'bar',] # True
```

Is there some way to do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839121/check-if-a-string-to-interpolate-provides-expected-placeholders-python

Answer (score 1):

Smth like

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("%\(([^\)]+)\)[sif]", "some text %(foo)s %(bar)s", re.M)
['foo', 'bar']
```

`[sif]` part can be extended with symbols from table on http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> S = "some text %(foo)s %(bar)s"
>>> print re.findall(r'%\((.*?)\)', S)
['foo', 'bar']
```